# SetProperty in BeanShell Post Processor

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

I have two thread groups in my test-plan.
First screen - I put "id" in variable "spaceId" (using JSON Extractor). [image]
Second screen - I use SetProperty in BeanShell PostProcessor[image]
In log I see that "spaceId" has value of my "id"[image]
But in API of second thread group value "space" is not getting my "id" code, it is null [image]
Can you say me where I have a mistake

Screenshots in block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to get the value of a JMeter Property, to wit change `${spaceIdNew}` to `${__P(spaceIdNew,)}`

In general using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). See [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) article for more details.